# Warning: Assignment from Incompatible Pointer Type [enabled by default] while assigning Function Address to Function Pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I am trying to implement a simple swap function using function pointer but when I assign the function's address to a function pointer:

`pointersTofunctionB.c:14:6:warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default].

This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void intSwap(int *a,int *b);
void charSwap(char *a,char *b);
void (*swap)(void*,void*);
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a=20,b=15;
    char c='j',d='H';
    swap=&intSwap;// warning here
    swap(&a,&b);
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
    swap=&charSwap;// warning here also
    swap(&c,&d);
    printf("%c %c\n",c,d ); 
    return 0;
}


void intSwap(int *a,int *b)
{
    *a=*a+*b;
    *b=*a-*b;
    *a=*a-*b;
}
void charSwap(char *a,char *b)
{
    char temp;
    temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}
```

How can I solve this warning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The warnings appear due to the following quote from the C Standard

6.3.2.3 Pointers

> 8 A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to
>   a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
>   equal to the original pointer. **If a converted pointer is used to
>   call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type,
>   the behavior is undefined.**

That two functions would be compatible their parameters shall have compatible types

6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)

> 15 For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify
>   compatible return types.146) Moreover, the parameter type lists, if
>   both are present, shall agree in the number of parameters and in use
>   of the ellipsis terminator; **corresponding parameters shall have
>   compatible types.**

In your functions parameters are declared as pointers. So that they (pointers) would be compatible they shall be pointers to compatible types

6.7.6.1 Pointer declarators

2 For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both **shall be pointers to compatible types.**

However types int or char on the one hand and type void on the other hand are not compatible types.

You could define your functions the following way

```
void intSwap( void *a, void *b )
{
    int *x = a;
    int *y = b;

    *x = *x + *y;
    *y = *x - *y;
    *x = *x - *y;
}

void charSwap( void *a, void *b )
{
    char *c1 = a;
    char *c2 = b;
    char temp = *c1;

    *c1 = *c2;
    *c2 = temp;
}
```

Comment: You could cast explicitly:
swap = (void ( * )(void*, void*))intSwap;
Since sizeof(void*) == sizeof(int*) this should be entirely safe and portable.

Comment: This would have the benefit of preserving typesafety in case you want to involve intSwap directly somewhere else...

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

```
 swap=&intSwap;
```

to

```
 swap=intSwap;
```

Same goes for `swap=&charSwap;` also.

Again, your function signature(s) does not match the function pointer signature.

Your function is

```
void intSwap(int *a,int *b);
```

which is of return type void, two input parameters of `int *`, whereas, your function pointer signature is

```
void (*swap)(void*,void*);
```

which takes two `void *`s. Same for `void charSwap` function also.

Either yoou have to change the function signature, or you have to use a different function pointer prototype. Otherwise, the behaviour is undefined. [as mentioned in Vlad's answer].

Comment: `&intSwap` evaluates to the same thing as `intSwap` by itself. It makes no difference if the ampersand is there or not.

Comment: @MichaelBurr You're right sir,they both evaluates to same thing. However I thought it's _recommended_ to write as `swap=intSwap;`. Please correct me I'm wrong.

Comment: I personally have no strong feelings either way, I'm not sure if others recommend leaving the ampersand off or not.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void intSwap(int *a,int *b);
void charSwap(char *a,char *b);
void (*swap)(int*,int*);
void (*swap1)(char*,char*);
int main()
{
    int a=20,b=15;
    char c='j',d='H';
    swap=&intSwap;// warning here
    swap(&a,&b);
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
    swap1=&charSwap;// warning here also
    swap1(&c,&d);
    printf("%c %c\n",c,d ); 
    return 0;
}


void intSwap(int *a,int *b)
{
    *a=*a+*b;
    *b=*a-*b;
    *a=*a-*b;
}
void charSwap(char *a,char *b)
{
    char temp;
    temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}

**If you want you can use like it......**
```

Comment: instead doing like how you have mentioned I can simply use the corresponding function name itself. I want to show the the use of function pointer but the modification which you have mentioned wont be sufficient for it.

Comment: `using namespace std;`? The question is about C, not C++.

Answer (score -6):

To remove the warning, code this overload:

```
void (*swap)(int *,int*);

void (*swap)(char *,char*);
```

Comment: what is this? can you elaborate please?