# Does this function I made correctly append a string to another string?

Tags: c, string, char, concatenation, c99

I was up coding at 3 AM last night, and I wake up today and find this in a source file: (curse words redacted)

```c
void append_this_stuff(char *stuff_to_append_to[], char **stuff_to_append, int position) {
  char the_actual_stuff[] = *(stuff_to_append_to);
  char *screw_me = *(stuff_to_append);

  int someNumber = strlen(screw_me);

  int j = 0;
  for (int i = position; i < (someNumber + position - 1); i++) {
    the_actual_stuff[i] = (screw_me + j);
    j++;
  } 

  stuff_to_append_to = &the_actual_stuff;
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get this error:

```
<project root>/src/brstring.c: In function ‘append_this_stuff’:
<project root>/src/brstring.c:38:28: error: invalid initializer
   char the_actual_stuff[] = *(stuff_to_append_to);
                            ^
<project root>/src/brstring.c:46:24: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     the_actual_stuff[i] = (screw_me + j);
                        ^
<project root>/src/brstring.c:50:21: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   stuff_to_append_to = &the_actual_stuff;
```

Does anyone have any idea if I'm doing this right? I'm compiling via the C99 standard and cmake and I'm using GCC on Fedora Linux, should that affect anything.

Comment: Why are you using c99? C11 has been out for a long time and is widely supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `char *stuff_to_append_to[]` is an *array of pointers of undetermined length*, that is not a valid parameter, as the last dimension of an array must be specified when passed to a function, otherwise, pass a pointer to type.

Next, `char **stuff_to_append` is a *pointer to pointer to char* and is completely valid, but given your use of `stuff_to_append` within the function, it is obvious that is not what you intended.

If you wish to **insert** `stuff_to_append` and **truncate** `stuff_to_append_to` at the end of `stuff_to_append` simply pass a pointer to each string as the argument. While `int position` is fine, a choice of an *unsigned* value may be better as you will not insert at a *negative* array index.

Inside your function, you must validate there is sufficient space in `stuff_to_append_to` to hold `stuff_to_append` beginning at index `position` (including space for the *nul-byte*)

With that in mind, you may want to do something like the following:

```
void append_this_stuff (char *stuff_to_append_to, char *stuff_to_append, 
                        int position) 
{
    int somenumber = strlen (stuff_to_append),
        lento = strlen (stuff_to_append_to),
        end = position + somenumber;

    if (end > lento) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient space in stuff_to_append_to.\n");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = position; i < end + 1; i++)    /* +1 to force copy of nul-byte */
        stuff_to_append_to[i] = stuff_to_append[i - position];
}
```

You can write a small test program to confirm it's operation, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
...
int main (void) {

    char stuff[] = "my dog has fleas!",
        append[] = "cat has none!";
    int pos = 3;

    printf ("original: %s\n", stuff);
    append_this_stuff (stuff, append, pos);
    printf ("     new: %s\n", stuff);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/append
original: my dog has fleas!
     new: my cat has none!
```

To do the same thing using *pointer arithmetic* instead of using *array indexes*, you can rewrite `append_this_stuff` similar to the following:

```
void ats (char *to, char *from, int p)
{
    if (p + strlen (from) > strlen (to)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient space in stuff_to_append_to.\n");
        return;
    }

    for (to += p; *from; to++, from++)
        *to = *from;
    *to = *from;
}
```

Lastly, if this lesson is not completely ingrained in your thought process, "*Never post anything that you would not want in the hands of the recruiter as you interview for your first programming position.*" The use of unprofessional or cute variable names, while it may express your frustrations, may not give the impression you want in the hands of another. Enough said.

Comment: It looks like this works. I'll also keep this lesson in mind and filter all the swears out of my code. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, glad to help, just take it as a bit of advise from a crusty old lawyer and engineer who knows of what he speaks...

Answer (score 0):

1.) error: invalid initializer:

```
char the_actual_stuff[] = *(stuff_to_append_to);
```

The_actual_stuff is an array without an initial size. Did you mean to use a pointer to point to a memory address?

2.) warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast:

```
the_actual_stuff[i] = (screw_me + j);
```

You are trying to assign a value to an array index that has no initial size.

A  side note: if you meant to add the values of the variables together you must first dereference the pointer with a *. You are adding an integer to a memory address.

3.) warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

```
  stuff_to_append_to = &the_actual_stuff;
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632217/warning-assignment-from-incompatible-pointer-type-enabled-by-default-while-as): as it explains it nicely.