# Concatenate char array and char

Tags: c, arrays, string, concatenation

I am new to C language. I need to concatenate char array and a char. In java we can use '+' operation but in C that is not allowed. Strcat and strcpy is also not working for me. How can I achieve this? My code is as follows

```
void myFunc(char prefix[], struct Tree *root) {
    char tempPrefix[30];
    strcpy(tempPrefix, prefix);
    char label = root->label;
    //I want to concat tempPrefix and label
```

My problem differs from [concatenate char array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218290/concatenate-char-array-in-c) as it concat char array with another but mine is a char array with a char

Comment: Possible duplicate of [concatenate char array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218290/concatenate-char-array-in-c)

Comment: added an explanation how mine is differ from previous question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: See also [**Does this function I made correctly append a string to another string?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422030/does-this-function-i-made-correctly-append-a-string-to-another-string/43422468#43422468)

Comment: Create a temporary string then copy it. `strcat(tempPrefix, (char[2]){ root->label, '\0'});`

Comment: Alternatively, `size_t length = strlen(tempPrefix);
tempPrefix[length] = root->label;
tempPrefix[length+1] = '\0';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather simple really. The main concern is that `tempPrefix` should have enough space for the prefix + original character. Since C strings must be null terminated, your function shouldn't copy more than 28 characters of the prefix. It's 30(the size of the buffer) - 1 (the root label character) -1 (the terminating null character). Fortunately the standard library has the [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy):

```
size_t const buffer_size = sizeof tempPrefix; // Only because tempPrefix is declared an array of characters in scope. 
strncpy(tempPrefix, prefix, buffer_size - 3);
tempPrefix[buffer_size - 2] = root->label;
tempPrefix[buffer_size - 1] = '\0';
```

It's also worthwhile not to hard code the buffer size in the function calls, thus allowing you to increase its size with minimum changes.

---

If your buffer isn't an exact fit, some more legwork is needed. The approach is pretty much the same as before, but a call to [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) is required to complete the picture.

```
size_t const buffer_size = sizeof tempPrefix; // Only because tempPrefix is declared an array of characters in scope. 
strncpy(tempPrefix, prefix, buffer_size - 3);
tempPrefix[buffer_size - 2] = tempPrefix[buffer_size - 1] = '\0';
*strchr(tempPrefix, '\0') = root->label;
```

We again copy no more than 28 characters. But explicitly pad the end with NUL bytes. Now, since `strncpy` fills the buffer with NUL bytes up to `count` in case the string being copied is shorter, in effect everything after the copied prefix is now `\0`. This is why I deference the result of `strchr` right away, it is guaranteed to point at a valid character. The first free space to be exact.

Comment: I am not getting expected output here. I can see appended char is in 28th location of my tempPrefix char array but when I print it, it is not there. Shouldn't we concat to the next location of current text in array rather than to the end of array.

Comment: @GeorgeKlimas - Minor mistake on my part. `strncpy` copies *at most* count characters, inclusive. That means the call to it needs to be adjusted. See my edit for the detail.

Comment: Still I am not getting appended character in the char array. Debug shows me that character is being appended to 28 position.

Comment: @GeorgeKlimas - Yes, I was editing that fix into the question, since I misunderstood the parameters of your problem initially.

Comment: @GeorgeKlimas - NP. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

`strXXX()` family of functions mostly operate on *strings* (except the searching related ones), so you will not be able to use the library functions directly.

You can find out the position of the existing null-terminator, replace that with the `char` value you want to concatenate and add a null-terminator after that. However, you need to make sure you have got enough room left for the source to hold the concatenated *string*.

Something like this (not tested)

```
#define SIZ 30


//function
char tempPrefix[SIZ] = {0};     //initialize
strcpy(tempPrefix, prefix);    //copy the string
char label = root->label;      //take the char value

if (strlen(tempPrefix) < (SIZ -1))   //Check: Do we have room left?
{
    int res = strchr(tempPrefix, '\0');  // find the current null
    tempPrefix[res] = label;             //replace with the value
    tempPrefix[res + 1] = '\0';          //add a null to next index
}
```

Comment: I am not getting the output here. I can see `res` is getting minus values. Is it the problem ?